# Multiplying every element in a Convergent Series by a positive, monotonically increasing but bounded sequence. Still convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{b_n\}$ be a monotonically increasing, positive, and bounded (therefore convergent) sequence. And let $a_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i$ be a convergent series. I feel like the series

$$
a'_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n b_i x_i
$$

Should also converge. This is clearly true in the case where $a_n$ is absolutely convergent but I can't seem to prove it in the general case. I've searched around but I can't seem to find an answer to this specific question which makes me feel my feeling is false. Can someone help with the proof/counter example?

For context, this more general question sprouted from the problem: Given the $a_n$ as defined above would the sequence $s_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{i}{n} x_i$ converge? Guidance on this would also be very helpful thanks!

Comment: This fact generally holds for convergent $b_i$. Try to show that the modified series is Cauchy, using the fact that the original series is Cauchy and that for $i$ large enough, $b_i$ is within an $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of its limit $b$.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos: I have been reading a paper which has a step which appears to depend on this claim. I have tried very hard to show the Cauchy property for the modified series and have not succeeded. I was just about to post my own question when I saw that it duplicated this one. If you could provide an answer or a more detailed hint, I would be very grateful.

Comment: I now learn that this result is known as Abel's criterion for convergence of real series and its proof involves summation by parts. See https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Abel_criterion.